# What are the file types supported in amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to upload dat,txt,xlsx files to amazon s3 bucket, Are these files supported in Amazon s3?

Comment: It's not a good practice to just dump your question here and let other works on it. You should try to resolve it first , or do search by your self. It's a google search away, and there's so many AWS S3 documentation and tutorial that this is a very common topic. Follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i couldn't find so i posted here@NAVIN

Comment: Then share your finding's. Let other know what you have already covered so can direct you to right path, or share info where you should be looking.

Comment: Did you tried to upload any document to S3? This will be more clear.

Comment: i have uploaded xlsx file to amazon s3 bucket and tried to query it.                           `select * from `s3.default`.`Financial Sample.xlsx`` **i got error  drill failed to execute the query**

Comment: Well you can store any kind of data in any format in AWS S3, and file can be of any size. Check this link [General S3 FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/).

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html please go through the link above where only few file formats are supported @NAVIN

Comment: @user10512791 your question needs clarification.  S3 has no limits on what kinds of files it can store...  but you appear to be asking about [S3 Select Object Content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html).  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, I want to perform select operation on the object I uploaded, we can upload any file but can we perform select operation on any file? @Michael - sqlbot

Comment: I am using apache drill @Michael - sqlbot

Comment: @NAVIN a google search brought me here

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Any type of file can be uploaded and stored in Amazon S3.

Comment: yes we can but i am using apache drill, Is it possible to query on xlsx and txt files just like csv and json @John Rotenstein

Comment: That was not in your question. Your question merely says "Are these files supported in Amazon s3?" Please either edit your question with full details, or create a new question with complete information.